# Matplotlib freezes when trying to render latex

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, tex-live

I am new to matplotlib and latex. I tried to run this example from their [website](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html) **locally** on my computer:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# interface tracking profiles
N = 500
delta = 0.6
X = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)
ax.plot(X, (1 - np.tanh(4 * X / delta)) / 2,    # phase field tanh profiles
        X, (1.4 + np.tanh(4 * X / delta)) / 4, "C2",  # composition profile
        X, X < 0, "k--")                        # sharp interface

# legend
ax.legend(("phase field", "level set", "sharp interface"),
          shadow=True, loc=(0.01, 0.48), handlelength=1.5, fontsize=16)

# the arrow
ax.annotate("", xy=(-delta / 2., 0.1), xytext=(delta / 2., 0.1),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", connectionstyle="arc3"))
ax.text(0, 0.1, r"$\delta$",
        color="black", fontsize=24,
        horizontalalignment="center", verticalalignment="center",
        bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="white", ec="black", pad=0.2))

# Use tex in labels
ax.set_xticks([-1, 0, 1])
ax.set_xticklabels(["$-1$", r"$\pm 0$", "$+1$"], color="k", size=20)

# Left Y-axis labels, combine math mode and text mode
ax.set_ylabel(r"\bf{phase field} $\phi$", color="C0", fontsize=20)
ax.set_yticks([0, 0.5, 1])
ax.set_yticklabels([r"\bf{0}", r"\bf{.5}", r"\bf{1}"], color="k", size=20)

# Right Y-axis labels
ax.text(1.02, 0.5, r"\bf{level set} $\phi$",
        color="C2", fontsize=20, rotation=90,
        horizontalalignment="left", verticalalignment="center",
        clip_on=False, transform=ax.transAxes)

# Use multiline environment inside a `text`.
# level set equations
eq1 = (r"\begin{eqnarray*}"
       r"|\nabla\phi| &=& 1,\\"
       r"\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + U|\nabla \phi| &=& 0 "
       r"\end{eqnarray*}")
ax.text(1, 0.9, eq1, color="C2", fontsize=18,
        horizontalalignment="right", verticalalignment="top")

# phase field equations
eq2 = (r"\begin{eqnarray*}"
       r"\mathcal{F} &=& \int f\left( \phi, c \right) dV, \\ "
       r"\frac{ \partial \phi } { \partial t } &=& -M_{ \phi } "
       r"\frac{ \delta \mathcal{F} } { \delta \phi }"
       r"\end{eqnarray*}")
ax.text(0.18, 0.18, eq2, color="C0", fontsize=16)

ax.text(-1, .30, r"gamma: $\gamma$", color="r", fontsize=20)
ax.text(-1, .18, r"Omega: $\Omega$", color="b", fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

When I first tried it, it crashed, telling me I need to install latex. So, I installed texlive and tried again. This time it didn't crash but the window just froze and didn't display anything. Do you have any idea how to run this example?

I need to run it locally (not in ipython or jupyter) because it's part of a desktop project I am working on. I am using Windows 10 if it helps anyone figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wait a while. Took like 10 - 20 seconds here for the content to show up.

Comment: You were right. A shame that it takes that long to load. Can you explain what slows it down? The latex rendering is really that difficult?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how Matplotlib and (La)TeX actually interact. Generating a (La)TeX documents takes some time, but not as much as the script. So I'd guess it's the integration of the (La)TeX output into the plot. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Works fine for me on linux. I would suggest you change the last line to `fig.show()` instead

Answer (score 0):

While not a proper solution, but if you have only a few lines of LaTeX, you could try putting `usetex=True` like below, while not setting `matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`.

```py
ax.set_ylabel(r"\bf{phase field} $\phi$", color="C0", fontsize=20, usetex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, matplotlib "freezes" for a long time to render a graph. I changed the backend to postscript to make things work faster.

```
plt.rcParams["backend"] = "ps"
```